# I just found odd URLs in my Apache logs

Tags: apache-2.2, log-files

I was using Tail on an Apache log file and noticed these:

```
/cie/insxp5/update.ins 
/rpam/homepage-e.asp
/rpam/Training-e.asp
```

From a short session of googling, I think the rpam URLs refer to either Ruby or Redmine authentication? The other URL seems to indicate an attempt to log onto a device with LaCie Remote Administration?

Not sure if others have seen this before?

**Edit #1**
Long story short, links containing /rpam are actually valid request. Those containing /cie still are up in the air.

Comment: Get used to it - this is just some of the noise you will see on an internet connected machine.

Comment: they love phpmyadmin for sure.

Comment: @thkang Amen to that. It's fascinating seeing them trying dozens of different common phpmyadmin URLs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are bots scanning your server for known vulnerabilities of the applications you mentioned.